# Google AppEngine in Intellij

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea, google-cloud-intellij

How do I set up the Google App Engine in IntelliJ?  I think I'm missing something here.

I see that they have app engine i[nstructions on IntelliJ's site](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/google_app_engine.html), but I don't see how to install it into Intellij.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that the Google App Engine is available in the Community Edition. Otherwise it is available as a plugin in the Ultimate Edition. It should have been available directly after installation unless you deliberately unchedked it.

**Ultimate Edition plugins, Google App Engine Integration plugin available.**

[image]

**Community Edition plugins, no Google App Engine Integration plugin :-(**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is now a [Google Cloud Plugin for Intellij](https://cloud.google.com/intellij/) [(docs)](https://cloud.google.com/tools/intellij/docs/) [(github)](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-intellij).

App Engine [(Standard)](https://cloud.google.com/tools/intellij/docs/deploy-std) [(Flexible)](https://cloud.google.com/tools/intellij/docs/deploy-flex)
[(Stackdriver Debugger)](https://cloud.google.com/tools/intellij/docs/debugger)

Comment: FYI this plugin adds App Engine support for both Ultimate and Community editions of IntelliJ.